# Legacy Java Syntax

Tags: java, legacy

Reading the [Java Code Conventions document from 1997](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf), I saw this in an example on P16 about variable naming conventions:

```
int i;
char *cp;
float myWidth;
```

The second declaration is of interest - to me it looks a lot like how you might declare a pointer in C. It gives a syntax error when compiling under Java 8.

Just out of curiosity: was this ever valid syntax? If so, what did it mean?

Comment: Yes, that's C - must have been a copy/paste error.

Comment: this was never a valid syntax

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I salute you - the one who reads the documentation!

Answer (score 25):

It's a copy-paste error, I suppose.

From JLS 1 (which is *really* not that easy to find!), the section on [local variable declarations](http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-1.0/14.doc.html#5920) states that such a declaration, in essence, is a type followed by an identifier. Note that there is no special reference made about `*`, but there is special reference made about `[]` (for arrays).

`char` is our type, so the only possibility that remains is that `*cp` is an identifier. The [section on *Identifiers*](http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-1.0/3.doc.html#40625) states

> An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java
>   digits, the first of which must be a Java letter.
>   
> ...
>   
> A Java letter is a character for which the method Character.isJavaLetter ([§20.5.17](http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-1.0/javalang.doc4.html#9516)) returns true

And [the JavaDoc for that method](http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-1.0/javalang.doc4.html#9516) states:

> A character is considered to be a Java letter if and only if it is a
>   letter ([§20.5.15](http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-1.0/javalang.doc4.html#9163)) or is the dollar sign character '$' (`\u0024`) or the
>   underscore ("low line") character '_' (`\u005F`).

so `foo`, `_foo` and `$foo` were fine, but `*foo` was never valid.

---

If you want a more up-to-date Java style guide, [Google's style guide](http://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html) is the arguably the most commonly referenced.

Comment: But in e.g. C++, `*` is part of the *type specifier*, not an identifier. I wouldn't expect  the C++ spec to mention `*` *in the section on identifiers*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever True, but given that the example lists `char *cp`, `char` is necessarily a type (because it's a keyword), so `*cp` is necessarily an identifier (as per [14.3](http://titanium.cs.berkeley.edu/doc/java-langspec-1.0/14.doc.html#5920)). It's impossible to point to a single point in the spec which says that `*` has no special meaning (other than being the multiplication operator), so not possible to cite it.

Comment: Going even further back in time, the [Oak Specification](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~waldo/oakSpec.pdf) did not mention `*` and pointers (explicitly) either.

Comment: @Marco13: That's an interesting read. I didn't know Oak had support for Design-by-Contract and that it supported Uniform Access. Also, the public-key signed packages with access restrictions look interesting for a language that is used for running of untrusted code from the network.

Comment: Interestingly you can still get a printed version of JLS 1.0 (ISBN-10: 0201634511) https://www.amazon.com/Java-TM-Language-Specification/dp/0201634511 - https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=560667

Comment: @Caramiriel A literal paperweight :)

Answer (score 5):

It appears that this is a generic coding style document for C-like languages with some Java-specific additions. See, for example, also the next page:

> Do not use the assignment operator in a place where it can be easily confused with the equality operator. Example:
>
> ```
> if (c++ = d++) { // AVOID! Java disallows.
>     …
> }
> ```

It does not make sense to tell a programmer to avoid something that is a syntax error anyway, so the only conclusion we can draw from this is that the document is not 100% Java-specific.

Another possibility is that it was meant as a coding style for the entire Java system, including the C++ parts of the JRE and JDK.

Note that Sun abandoned the coding style document even long before Oracle came into the picture. They restrained themselves to specifying what the language *is*, not how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Invalid syntax!

It's just a copy/paste mistake.

The Token (*) in variables is applicable only in C because it uses pointers whereas JAVA never uses pointers.

And Token (*) is used only as operator in JAVA.